# Remove text from my Facebook posts

Tags: facebook

At first, I'm sorry for my english, I'll try to do my best because I'm Argentinian.

I am using publicize to send my wordpress post's to my Facebook Fanpage.

This is how publicize send automatic posts.

[image]
And I just need to delete description to send posts like this:

[image]

What should I do? I am trying to solve this but I can't.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you look at this answer. Similiar to your question. If you change some variables you can delete description or add more specific things. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/226281/23042

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm sorry but I don't understand :( should I paste thise code in my functions.php then my problem is solved?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Answer's code add hashtags to content bu youcan change `$custom_message = $content . ' ' . $hash_tags;` to `$custom_message = get_the_permalink();` will resolve your problem. I will add answer with corrected code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Jetpack's publicize description with this code. Add this code to your theme's `functions.php`

```
// Remove description of posts on social share
if ( class_exists( 'Jetpack' ) && Jetpack::is_module_active( 'publicize' ) ) {
    function tsj_publicize_hashtags() {
        $post = get_post();
        if ( ! empty( $post ) ) {
                $custom_message = get_the_permalink(); 
                update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wpas_mess', $custom_message );
        }
    }
    /* Save that message */
    function tsj_cust_pub_message_save() {
    add_action( 'save_post', 'tsj_publicize_hashtags', 21 );
    }
    add_action( 'publish_post', 'tsj_cust_pub_message_save' );
}
```

Respond me if code works.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply! I've tested this code but it doesn't work :/

I already added this code to my functions.php

Comment: apparently it worked for twitter posts (I can only see my link on my twitters posts, not thumb or description). I don't want to change twitter settings I just want to change Facebook format posts...

How can I do? Thanks!

Comment: In Jetpack, custom messages probably same for all sharing platform. I will check documentation.

Comment: So, there is no chance to custom facebook posts? I just need to delete description and stay with title+link .
So, I think we can delete only description, right?

Comment: Anyone else could help me, please? :/